# How to use navigateUp to close the application

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the Android Navigation component.

Inside my HomeFragment I'm adding a `OnBackPressedCallback`

```
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            doStuff();
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigateUp();
        }
    };

    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
```

The problem is that `navigateUp` is not closing the application.

I tried to pop the stack but nothing changes.

What should I do?

Thank you

Comment: Is `HomeFragment` startDestination? Why not just use `activity.finish`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the [`navigateUp()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#navigateUp()) and [`popBackStack()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()), both return a `boolean` value indicating:

> `true` if the stack was popped and the user has been navigated to another destination, `false` otherwise

The NavController only controls its own back stack (i.e., the destinations you've put on the back stack) and does not contain or operate on the activity back stack.

If you just want to always finish your activity when the back button is pressed, directly calling `requireActivity().finish()` is indeed the correct thing to do.

Otherwise, you should be conditionally calling `requireActivity().finish()` only if `popBackStack()`/`navigateUp()` return false - that's your sign that there's nothing else on the NavController back stack and you need to handle the back stack yourself.

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between `popBackStack()` and `navigateUp`? Because I found them do the same functionality.